# how to debug python in visual studio (how to step in a library)?

Tags: python, visual-studio

I'm writing python in visual studio 2015. I want to ask how to step into a library if I'm using a function that is defined in the library.

For example, I wrote the following code,

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model, datasets
np.random.seed(0)
regdata = datasets.make_regression(100, 1, noise = 20.0)
```

And I want to step into the makeregression() function at 4th line (this function is defined in samples_generator.py, scikit-learn package) to see what is happening inside of the function. When I press F11(shortcut for step into) in visual studio, instead of moving into samples_generator.py, the arrow just moves to next line of my code.

Is there a way to let me step into a function which is defined in a library? 
Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try to use the option "Enable debugging of the Python standard library" in Python Tools:

[image: Python Tools]

To get here, open Tools->Options->Python Tools->Debugging in Visual Studio.